# Update statement with join on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query but it's not working. Can you tell me the solution?

```
update temp_msisdn_saldo 
    set saldo=(
        select sum(saldo) from (
            select a.msisdn as mdn, a.saldo from temp_msisdn_saldo a 
            union all
            select b.mdn as mdn, b.saldo from temp_msisdn_saldo_yesterday b 
        ) z
    )
where msisdn=z.mdn
```

Comment: It is difficult to debug "It is not working". What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite it as :

```
update temp_msisdn_saldo 
      set saldo = ( select sum(saldo) 
                    from (select a.msisdn as mdn, a.saldo 
                          from temp_msisdn_saldo a 
                          union all
                          select b.mdn as mdn, b.saldo 
                          from temp_msisdn_saldo_yesterday b 
                         ) z
                     where z.mdn = temp_msisdn_saldo.msisdn
                  );
```

Same you can use `CTE` :

```
with cte as (
     <your query here>
)

update temp_msisdn_saldo 
      set saldo = (select sum(c.saldo) from cte c where c.mdn = temp_msisdn_saldo.msisdn);
```